# if/else with multiple conditions R

Tags: r, if-statement

Here is a dummy df

```
df <- data.frame(
  feature = c("length","weight","roundness","length","weight","roundness"), 
  value = c(7.9,14.2,9.4,30.8,33.7,26.6), 
  gender=c("male","male","male","female","female","female"))
```

I would like to add an extra ref column to the df representing a reference value according to some conditions within the gender group:

grouping by gender if value for roundness is > 15 print roundness value otherwise if roundness < 15 print length value.
Below the output that I'm looking for.

```
    feature value gender  ref
1    length   7.9   male  7.9
2    weight  14.2   male  7.9
3 roundness   9.4   male  7.9
4    length  30.8 female 26.6
5    weight  33.7 female 26.6
6 roundness  26.6 female 26.6
```

I wanted to use the if else function but I do not know the syntax in this case, I know the code is wrong.

```
df$ref<- df %>% group_by(gender) %>% 
  if (feature%in%"roundness" & df$value > 15 ){value of df roundness} else {(value of df length)}
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

One way may be to use `tidyr` to pivot and `dplyr` for the conditions:

```
df %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = value, names_from = feature) %>%
  group_by(gender) %>%
  mutate(ref = case_when(
    roundness > 15 ~ roundness,
    roundness < 15 ~ length
  )) %>%
  pivot_longer(length:roundness)
```

Note it wasn't clear what you want if roundness equaled 15 exactly, so you may want to put `<=` or `>=` instead of only `<` and `>` - the current code will give `NA` for `roundness == 15`.

Output:

```
  gender   ref name      value
  <chr>  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
1 male     7.9 length      7.9
2 male     7.9 weight     14.2
3 male     7.9 roundness   9.4
4 female  26.6 length     30.8
5 female  26.6 weight     33.7
6 female  26.6 roundness  26.6
```

Comment: I need to study the code, but it works indeed. Thanks a lot